# Why can't I link my Skype contacts with the rest in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, skype

I'm using Skype in Empathy thanks to telepathy-haze and pidgin-skype. I've also added MSN, Jabber (Gtalk), and Facebook. When I link contacts from MSN, Gtalk, and Facebook, there's no problem, but if I include a Skype contact, either nothing happens or Empathy crashes and after restarting I see that the Skype contact was never linked.

Is the fact that Skype is not natively supported in Telepathy a problem for linking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is probably due to using an unsupported protocol in Empathy

To confirm of this, you can test Adding the contact in Pidgin, and if it still crashes, report a bug on the binary `pidgin-skype`

See more on [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)